# minus on down-vote or flagging

Tags: support, down-votes

I just saw a post, where there were one answer, the answer said something like: *"I also need blahblah, can you share project I need please"*.

I down-voted and flagged it as *not an answer* this seemed to have earned me *-1* reputation on stack overflow, why is this? Is it because someone doesn't agree with my down vote, or I flagged it incorrectly or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> there were one answer
>
> [...]
>
> I down-voted

You get -1 rep for [downvoting an answer](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Just to add that the -1 will be restored after the downvoted post has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks I had missed that, especially thanks for the link with it I will no longer have the need for asking stupid questions here ;)